# constexpr to substitute macros without regression

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr, compile-time

In our company in the code we use 64bit flag enums:

```
enum Flags : unsigned long long {
    Flag1 =  1uLL<<0, // 1
    //...
    Flag40 = 1uLL<<40 // 1099511627776
};
```

And adding comments to see each flag decimal value even if we read the code in a text viewer. The problem is that nothing prevents a dev to put a wrong number in a comment.

There is a solution for this problem - a template with static_assert + a macro to use this approach easily - no need to use parenthesis and to add ::val everywhere:

```
template <unsigned long long i, unsigned long long j>
struct SNChecker{
    static_assert(i == j, "Numbers not same!");
    static const unsigned long long val = i;
};

#define SAMENUM(i, j) SNChecker<(i), (j)>::val

enum ET : unsigned long long {
    ET1 =     SAMENUM(1uLL<<2, 4),
    ET2fail = SAMENUM(1uLL<<3, 4), // compile time error
    ET4 =     SAMENUM(1uLL<<40, 1099511627776uLL),
};
```

It all looks good, but we are not really fond of macros.

A question: can we do same with constexpr function, but without errors readability regression?

The closest solution I could think of is:

```
constexpr unsigned long long SameNum(unsigned long long i, unsigned long long j)
{
    return (i == j) ? i : (throw "Numbers not same!");
}
```

but it generates an compile time error

```
error: expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression
```

instead of whatever I write in the static_assert

Edit:

The answer below is almost perfect except for one small regression: the call is a bit less pretty than using the macro.

One more approach (still worse than using static_assert but "prettier" in usage)

```
int NumbersNotSame() { return 0; }

constexpr unsigned long long SameNum(unsigned long long i, unsigned long long j)
{
    return (i == j) ? i : (NumbersNotSame());
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good reason why not to have a comment.  Why do you care that the base 10 value is `1099511627776uLL`?  Reading or displaying bit flags in base 10 seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: It's our company work specifics.  Our QAs - who test the flags in DB - read our .h files, so it's easier for them to have decimal representation.

Comment: Have you considered teaching your QA hex?

Comment: It's much easier to have dec results nearby.   Sometimes we even have flags like  1 << (GROUP_START + 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

static_assert in constexpr function:

```
template<unsigned long long I, unsigned long long J>
constexpr unsigned long long SameNum()
{
    static_assert(I == J, "numbers don't match");
    return I;
}

enum ET : unsigned long long {
    ET1 =     SameNum<1uLL<<2, 4>(),
    ET2fail = SameNum<1uLL<<3, 4>(), // compile time error
    ET4 =     SameNum<1uLL<<40, 1099511627776uLL>(),
};
```